# Object with same name is not able to be clicked on multiple times in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, katalon-studio

I have a button that supports text boxes, drop down menu. So I click on the button once and it brings up a new page.  If I try to click on the button the second time I receive an error that the object (button) is not found.

Anyone please help me to resolve this issue. I am attaching my code below.

```
WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_SelectAmbCol.CptDr.Duke'), 
    '13', true)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/input_pax1_firstName'), 'n')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/input_pax1_lastName'), 'n')

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_SelectFemaleMaleNA'), 
    '1', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_SelectAfghanAlbanianAlg'), 
    '15', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Day'), 
    '17', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Month'), 
    '09', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Year2006200520042003200'), 
    '19', true)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/a_Next Passenger'))

WebUI.delay(4)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services (1)/select_SelectAmbCol.CptDr.Duke_1'), 
    '16', true)

WebUI.delay(4)

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/input_chd1_firstName'), 'k')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/input_chd1_lastName'), 'k')

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_SelectFemaleMaleNA_1'), 
    '0', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Day                    _1'), 
    '15', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Month                  _1'), 
    '11', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_Year2016201520142013201'), 
    '4', true)

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/select_SelectAfghanAlbanianAlg_1'), 
    '13', true)

WebUI.delay(5)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('CreateBookingWithChildandInfant_Transit_OR/Page_Al-Maha Services/a_Next Passenger'))

WebUI.delay(5)
```

In above a-Next Passenger is working fine in first time. But it fails when on second page.

Comment: Is the given button available on second page too?

Comment: yes.It is available in second page too

Comment: Can you please share your error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this:

1. xpath/locator used might be different on both pages for same button

if this is not the case, you can also try adding below condition before clicking on the button:

waitforelementtobevisible, waitforelementtobeclickable
and then click on it.